# How to get over this Heroku-Redis error? SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku-redis

I am building a Django app using django channels and redis.
Running it locally on redis works fine but when pushing it on Heroku with Heroku-Redis v6.0.12 i get the bellow error:
Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number.
My settings.py for the Redis part looks like this :

```
import os
...
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]
...
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'),
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
            "CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS": {
                "ssl_cert_reqs": None
            },
        }
    }
}

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": ['redis://:*****@****.amazonaws.com:27810'],
        },
    },
}
```

What am I doing wrong?